# UINavigation stack display weird message

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have 3 UIViewControllers, a MenuVC, a GameVC and a ResultVC.

From the MenuVC I go in the GameVC and when the game is finished I go in the ResultVC. When I press the button back in ResultVC, I come back in the MenuVC using segue (like unwindToList). After I go again in the GameVC and the following message appears 'Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .' and the progress bar in GameVC isn't working anymore.

MenuVC -> GameVC -> ResultVC -> MenuVC -> GameVC

I checked the navigation controller stack and everything is ok, no GameVC is instantiated.
I found that this message appears when you try to push a view twice but in the stack I have my view only once and the first time it works fine.

Did I miss something ?

Comment: If you have any screenshot or example code, it will be helpful. What I understand with this question is that you are pushing viewControllers, and not popping them out from navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I declared a static boolean in my GameVC which was not released by ARC. I don't understand why but now it's working. Sorry to annoyed you.